# How can I make customized number format conversion in given data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame which has two column. However, I need to convert the format of `psw` column in 5 digit integer from the current format. How can I automatically change 1 digit to 5 in `psw` column? How can I get this done in R easily? Thanks

Here is reproducible data.frame

```
mydat <- data.frame(ID=LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 6)],
                  psw=c(10501,3,80310,8930,234,1))

> mydat
  ID   psw
1  A 10501
2  B     3
3  C 80310
4  D  8930
5  E   234
6  F     1
```

This is my desired output:

```
> mydat
  ID   psw
1  A 10501
2  B 00003
3  C 80310
4  D 08930
5  E 00234
6  F 00001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that while keeping the `psw` column numeric, but you can format it to be a certain width as a character vector. Here are two methods for this:

In base R you can use `formatC()`:

```
mydat <- data.frame(ID=LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 6)],
                    psw=c(10501,3,80310,8930,234,1))

mydat$psw <- formatC(mydat$psw, width = 5, format = "d", flag = "0")
mydat
#   ID   psw
# 1  A 10501
# 2  B 00003
# 3  C 80310
# 4  D 08930
# 5  E 00234
# 6  F 00001
```

In `stringr`, you can use `str_pad()`:

```
install.packages("stringr")
library(stringr)
mydat <- data.frame(ID=LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 6)],
                    psw=c(10501,3,80310,8930,234,1))

mydat$psw <- str_pad(mydat$psw, width = 5, pad = "0")
mydat
#   ID   psw
# 1  A 10501
# 2  B 00003
# 3  C 80310
# 4  D 08930
# 5  E 00234
# 6  F 00001
```

Answer (score 1):

One can even use `sprintf` in `base-R`.

```
  mydat$psw <- sprintf("%05d",mydat$psw)

  mydat
  # ID   psw
  # 1  A 10501
  # 2  B 00003
  # 3  C 80310
  # 4  D 08930
  # 5  E 00234
  # 6  F 00001
```